# RedHat yum subversion installation

Tags: linux, svn, centos, redhat, yum

I am trying to install subversion on RedHat linux. But there is a bit problem with broken yum package manager. I have configured some own repositories from CentOS, but unfortunately there is still one broken dependency:

libneon.so.27

I have tried to download it on my own, but its dependencies are quite complex, it will cost me a lot of time to downlaod them all. Do you have any hints?
(Links to some repos with that libneon (rpmforge i have tried with no success))

Comment: We'd probably be able to help better if you were to post the yum output.

Comment: Finally after some longer time I obtained original installation CD for this distribution and then it was just one command installation. This is not first time I have run to similar problem with broken packages. It seems that even RedHat and Centos are quite similar distributions, there are still differences and without original packages it can make administrative tasks really troublesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download [rpm forge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge/) repository from the links [32 bit](http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.i686.rpm) or [64 bit](http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm) depending upon your machine configuration. rpm forge package has most of the useful packages and dependencies. After that try the following command:

```
yum install mod_dav_svn subversion
```

or just try

```
yum install subversion
```

In addition to subversion You can also use GIT which is similar to svn but has its own additional benefits.
If you like you can install [git](http://git-scm.com/) using the command:-

```
yum install git
```

Comment: The following forum indicates that the subversion packages have moved to the "rpmforge-extras" repo. Redhat might need to install with this `yum --enablerepo=rpmforge-extras install subversion mod_dav_svn` http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.rpm.rpmforge.user/1911

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito Was that enough for a *downvote*?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to downvote you, but I can't take it back because it hasn't been edited.

Comment: Each of three commands results in `Requires: libneon.so.27()(64bit)` with rpmforge-extras enabled.